# QT5 C++ QByteArray XML Parser

Tags: c++, xml, qt, parsing, qbytearray

I get the following xml

```
<Tra Type="SomeText">   
   <tr>Abcdefghij qwertzu</tr>
   <Rr X="0.0000" Y="0.0000" Z="0.0000" A="0.0000" B="0.0000" C="0.0000" />
   <Ar A1="0.0000" A2="0.0000" A3="0.0000" A4="0.0000" A5="0.0000" A6="0.0000" />
   <Er E1="0.0000" E2="0.0000" E3="0.0000" E4="0.0000" E5="0.0000" E6="0.0000" />
   <Te T21="1.09" T22="2.08" T23="3.07" T24="4.06" T25="5.05" T26="6.04" T27="7.03" T28="8.02" T29="9.01" T210="10.00" />
   <D>125</D>
   <IP></IP>
</Tra>
```

through a socket that saves it in a QByteArray called Data.

I want to extract and save every value from the xml to different variables (some as Integers some as QString's).

My main problem is that I dont know how to distinguish xml strings like `<D>125</D>` with a value in between the Tags and xml strings like `<Te T210="10.00" T29="9... />` that got the value in the Tag-String itself.

My code looks like this so far:

```
QByteArray Data = socket->readAll();

QXmlStreamReader xml(Data);
while(!xml.atEnd() && !xml.hasError())
{
.....  
}
```

Comment: That depends on the scheme for your XML - use readElementText() for text inside the element, and attributes() to access the attributes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's just so many examples already, aren't there?  =(

Anyway, like Frank said, if you want to read data (characters) from within tags - use [QXmlStreamReader::readElementText](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qxmlstreamreader.html#readElementText).

Alternatively, you can do this:

```
QXmlStreamReader reader(xml);
while(!reader.atEnd())
{  
  if(reader.isStartElement())
  {
    if(reader.name() == "tr")
    {
      reader.readNext();

      if(reader.atEnd()) 
        break;

      if(reader.isCharacters())
      {
        // Here is the text that is contained within <tr>
        QString text = reader.text().toString();
      }
    }
  }

  reader.readNext();
}
```

For attributes, you should use [QXmlStreamReader::attributes](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qxmlstreamreader.html#attributes) which will give you a container-type class of [attributes](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qxmlstreamattributes.html).

```
QXmlStreamReader reader(xml);
while(!reader.atEnd())
{  
  if(reader.isStartElement())
  {
    if(reader.name() == "Rr")
    {
      QXmlStreamAttributes attributes = reader.attributes();
      // This doesn't check if the attribute exists... just a warning.
      QString x = attributes.value("X").toString();
      QString y = attributes.value("Y").toString();
      QString a = attributes.value("A").toString();
      // etc...
    }
  }

  reader.readNext();
}
```

Comment: thanks very much! i am new to qt and c++. i know that there are many questions quite similar to this, but they are still kinda diffrent and its hard for me do distinguish between important/unimportant. anyway. big thx!

Comment: another question. why am i unable to print out the QStrings (for example  qDebug() << x; ) out of the while loop? Qt says that there is no declared identifier for x.

Comment: likely that the variable has gone out of scope?  maybe you need to include <QtDebug>

Comment: yep. already included :/ 
'C2065: 'estr': undeclared identifier' on the line i try to `qDebug() << x;`

Comment: QString x = attributes.value("X").toString(); qDebug() << x;

Comment: yep. my question is why does it not work if i set the qDebug part OUT of the while-loop.

Comment: yeah dude, then declare the variable before you enter the loop. then assign it, then print it out - http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/variables/ - read the part about variable scopes